# extract week from gives a rolling or a future week result

Tags: sql

I am using the following query

```
select extract(year from items.created_at) as year
      , extract(week from items.created_at) as week
  , count(items._id) as count
from items, accounts
where items.created_at >= '2022-01-01' 
and accounts._id = items.contextid 
and week>=42 and week<=52
group by
  1
  , 2
  , extract(week from items.created_at)
order by
  extract(year from items.created_at), extract(week from items.created_at)
```

While we are on week 51 (December 18th), I am getting results for week 52. How could it happen and how it can be avoided?
Is it possible that the results come from week 52 of previous year? or a rolling week issue?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag it.

Comment: maybe it depends on the definition of your "week", in some countries a week starts on sunday on others the week starts on monday, have a look at ISO-8601

Comment: Tip of the day: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

There is no data or table structure for reproducing, hence I may falsely assume here.

Your date starts at: items.created_at >= '2022-01-01'

I assume this is picking up week 52 from 2022. Was it meant to say 2023?

Be aware that if you mean to pick up the last portion of a year, some years have 53 weeks.

> and week>=42 and week<=52

select extract(week from '2023-12-31 00:00:00.000'); gives week 53 on MySQL.

Using SQL Server for an example, I can change my start date to get different week 53 beginnings. Hence use whatever your DB/organization is using.

[image]